Angular Google with ESlint No Explicit Any
We were required to add lint rules to our Angular app.
The specific rule that's causing an issue is the no-explicit-any eslint rule.
.eslintrc.json
"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
we are importing google maps on the app, but describing it as any would cause the linter to fail.  I can't seem to find the correct data type to use here.
declare const google: any;
I am also having issues with the other types, but I guess I can start with this for now. thanks!
any suggestions?
tried setting it to unknown but was having issues when accessing the map property on the google object


Some cases may be false positives you can just add a comment above the line, which will enforce, it ignores the line during linting!
// eslint-disable-next-line  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any

If you want to disable for the entire file, add this as the first line!
/* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */


First if you don't have it in your package.json, import
npm i -D @types/google.maps

Then you should be able to type your google const:
let map: google.maps.Map;

